# Why youtube iframe player eating away the rest of the html on the page?

Tags: iframe, youtube

**Fiddle link:** http://jsfiddle.net/T35fH/

Hi!

I m trying to have 2 iframe youtube video player on single page. but after first player is rendered the rest of page html simply disappears. These page needs to be mobile compatible so can't use the flash version :(

Any help please?

Thanks,
Anjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<iframe>` is NOT a single tag! Close it with `</iframe>`!  http://jsfiddle.net/qx9MN/

Comment: Damn! This simple thing and i was wondering all this time :( Thanks!